# Retrieve information from database and display in php

Tags: sql, database, return

When a user is on the search page and types in say `PatientID` then presses the search button, I want it to go to database and pull all information based on the `PatientID` entered.

I have tried this however no luck. It's returning a blank white screen.

```
<?php
    include 'connect.php';

    $id1 = $_POST['PatientID']; //Text box the user searches in
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM PatientRecords WHERE PatientID=$id1");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo 
        $row['PatientID'] . " " . 
        $row['FirstName']. " " . 
        $row['LastName']. " " . 
        $row['DOB']. " " . 
        $row['IDNumber1']. " " . 
        $row['Medication1']. " " . 
        $row['Medication1Dosage']. " " . 
        $row['IDNumber2']. " " . 
        $row['Medication2']. " " . 
        $row['Medication2Dosage']. " " . 
        $row['IDNumber3']. " " . 
        $row['Medication3']. " " . 
        $row['Medication3Dosage']. " " . 
        $row['MedicalNotes'];

        echo "<br />";
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM PatientRecords WHERE PatientID = $id1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Your query in wrong, In your query you are assigning :id1 to PatientID in where clause
that is nothing beacsue your id1 is store is in $id1 so use that instead of :id1
```

Your query

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM PatientRecords WHERE PatientID=$id1");
```

Comment: I have changed it now and still no luck ?